# Cannot connect to remote interpreter in Phpstorm 9

Tags: phpstorm

I have a remote server (Ubuntu 14) setup under Settings,Deployment with name RemoteServer connecting via SSH + private key. I can successfully browse remote files, edit, upload download etc.
Under Tools, Start SSH-Session, I can successfully use Terminal.

BUT

When I try to add this remote server to Languages & Frameworks,PHP, Interpreter - I cannot get it working. (I have equivalent setup with Vagrant working fine - I have deployment server called Vagrant-SSH and using interpreter from there in my project). Any attempt to connect to server fails when in Interpreters dialog.
Clicking on Deployment Host Url:  - ssh://me@remotesite.com:22 - brings up Test SFTP connection dialog - with Connection to 'mysite.com' failed.Connection failed. But, when I first add this php interpreter, it successfully uploads all the helpers into ~/.phpstorm_helpers. But then it claims that php is not installed at /usr/bin/php (that command does work). Clicking browse button again tells me error in connecting to mysite.com. I also tried setting up SSH credentials with same result (every so often I get a key error related to aes256-cbc not being supported - [I tried both PUTTY .ppk and OPEN-SSH version of same key]).

What can be causing this issue? Remember, in other parts of Phpstorm, this SSH config is working fine as mentioned above?

Can it be permissions related? I do not have advanced server admin permissions on server, but enough for day to day sftp + shell. Well, I tried running in my Phpstorm terminal (Based on Start SSH-Session->RemoteServer)

```
   cd .phpstorm_helpers
    php phpinfo.php
```

and it works fine - spitting out the relevant xml. So I have enough permissions to run the helpers and get useful results.

Can it be really related to Java handling of ssh keys? As pointed out, in other parts of phpstorm it works fine.

Comment: 1) Please enable extra logging for deployment operations (which includes SSH actions) 2) Submit support ticket together with your idea.log file (`Help | Show Log in...`). Without logs and hints on what exceptions are happening there it's not possible to give you any concrete advice based on your description (mainly due to the fact that it works here and fails there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in 9.0.1
[Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16603)